# Change font while using Bootstrap

Tags: css, fonts

im using Bootstrap framework but i want to change font from default to google font.

Im done something like this:

```
    <head>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Advent+Pro&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>

<style>
    body{
        font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif !important;
    }
</style>
```

When Bootstrap isnt included that code works fine, but when im "turning" Bootstrap font changing to default

All in all that code just not works and i dont know why...

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

In the head section of your html place your custom.css below bootstrap.css.

```
<link href="bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: name must be "custom.css"? or can be "somethinganother.css"?

Comment: @DKNS I think you need to take a basic course in how HTML & CSS work. Coding is a lot easier when you understand *why* something works, instead of just accepting that it works and moving on.

Comment: @DKNS you can give any name for your own css file...the fact what we are trying to achieve here is overiding the bootstrap.css file of your own css file, because you are placing your own css file just after the bootstrap.css loads , so your own styles mentioned in that custom css file will affect.

Comment: I just thought that bootstrap maybe have small api and u can change css just in css file with name custom XD

Comment: Try this link ..i have created a jsfiddle for you: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/18811/